# Switching between two bluetooth headsets in windows 7

Tags: bluetooth, switching, headphones

I am working on application that requires fast switching between two bluetooth headphones.
That would be just a part of larger software/hardware kit meant for improving communication with hearing impaired people. When sound level is below certain threshold headphones should be off. As soon as sound loudness exceeds threshold headphone should be turned on. I have already done something similar for one headset only. Now I need to expand that with possibility of using two headsets simultaneously. Is there any way, hardware or software, to achieve this ?